# AngularJS bind object parameter to object var

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code like this

```
$scope.grabItems = function(data) {
  data.model = ['test'];
  console.log($scope.ui.projects);
}

$scope.ui.projects = [];
$scope.grabProjects = function() {
  $scope.grabItems({model: $scope.ui.projects});
}
```

I'm trying to change the `$scope.ui.projects` variable using the parameter of another function (this is so that I can write an abstract grabItems function using any variable).

The problem is it looks like the `data.model = ['test']` isn't changing the `$scope.ui.projects` variable at all but is creating a brand new variable.

How would I modify the outer variable in a reusable way like this?

Note that `$scope.ui.projects` could potentially be any variable.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here, really.  It's clear from what you have mentioned in the comments to the other answers that you want to have some sort of "abstract" variable that could be any type, but that doesn't really make sense in context with angular, since the type would directly affect how the model is rendered in the output, so you must already know what kind of data it is....

Comment: essentially, it's not clear why you are trying to make the variables so generic or what problem this tactic would solve.  You have a very complex XY problem, where you have some unknown problem, and you are asking about your solution (making a generic function) but not explaining what purpose the generic function would serve.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually not changing `$scope.ui.projects`, Try like this

```
$scope.grabItems = function(data) {
  data.model = ['test'];
  console.log($scope.ui.projects);
}

$scope.ui.projects = [];
$scope.grabProjects = function() {
  $scope.grabItems($scope.ui.projects);
}
```

If it's not clear, share what is your expected object.

Comment: That's clear, the problem is that the `grabItems` function needs to change the variable based on the parameters passed in, so in the grabItems function I don't want to manually type in the variable name

Comment: @Jordash : you can change like `$scope.ui.projects.model = ['test'];`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, and in the comment `I don't want to manually type in the variable name` That is the whole purpose of doing the function like this.

Comment: `data.model` is supposed to be bound to `$scope.ui.projects` so that if I change that variable in the function it changes the root variable.

Comment: @Jordash : Try by calling like `$scope.grabItems($scope.ui.projects);`, as in ans

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by pushing items into the array:

```
$scope.grabItems = function(data) {
  if(!angular.isArray(data.model))
    throw new Error('Array expected');
  data.model.length = 0;       // empty array
  data.model.push('test');   // push items
  console.log($scope.ui.projects);
}

$scope.ui.projects = [];
$scope.grabProjects = function() {
  $scope.grabItems({model: $scope.ui.projects});
}
```

Comment: That works, the only issue is the variable could be array, object, or string